# How to pair mobile with embbeded board using bluez stack

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to pair bluetooth mobile device with my embedded board using bluez.

Now I am able to scan bt devices. But when I am firinf command "hcitool cc  and hcitool auth  then it showing no device connected.

Other that I used "rfcomm connect 0  1" then at mobile side its asking for PIN. I have added Pin at mobile side. But at board side could not able to pass the same key as I dont know the way How I could enter it from file or by some other way.

Please let me know which file I have to include for it and how i need to configure it.
I am using BLuex 5.18 stack.

hcidump :
< HCI Command: Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) plen 13
    bdaddr D4:93:98:C6:9A:DA ptype 0xcc18 rswitch 0x01 clkoffset 0x0000
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5

> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
>       Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) status 0x00 ncmd 1
>   HCI Event: Role Change (0x12) plen 8
>       status 0x00 bdaddr D4:93:98:C6:9A:DA role 0x01
>       Role: Slave
>   HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11
>       status 0x00 handle 1 bdaddr D4:93:98:C6:9A:DA type ACL encrypt 0x00
>   < HCI Command: Read Remote Supported Features (0x01|0x001b) plen 2
>       handle 1
>   HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
>       Read Remote Supported Features (0x01|0x001b) status 0x00 ncmd 1
>   HCI Event: Max Slots Change (0x1b) plen 3
>       handle 1 slots 5
>   HCI Event: Read Remote Supported Features (0x0b) plen 11
>       status 0x00 handle 1
>       Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x8f 0xfe 0xd8 0x3f 0x5b 0x87
>   < HCI Command: Read Remote Extended Features (0x01|0x001c) plen 3
>       handle 1 page 1
>   HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
>       Read Remote Extended Features (0x01|0x001c) status 0x00 ncmd 1
>   HCI Event: Read Remote Extended Features (0x23) plen 13
>       status 0x00 handle 1 page 1 max 1
>       Features: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 10
>       L2CAP(s): Info req: type 2
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 16
>       L2CAP(s): Info rsp: type 2 result 0
>         Extended feature mask 0x01b8
>           Enhanced Retransmission mode
>           Streaming mode
>           FCS Option
>           Fixed Channels
>           Extended Window Size
>   HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
>       handle 1 packets 1
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 10
>       L2CAP(s): Info req: type 3
>   HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
>       handle 1 packets 1
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 20
>       L2CAP(s): Info rsp: type 3 result 0
>         Fixed channel list 0x00000002
>           L2CAP Signalling Channel
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 12
>       L2CAP(s): Connect req: psm 3 scid 0x0040
>   HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
>       handle 1 packets 1
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 16
>       L2CAP(s): Connect rsp: dcid 0x0040 scid 0x0040 result 1 status 0
>         Connection pending - No futher information available
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 10
>       L2CAP(s): Info req: type 2
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 16
>       L2CAP(s): Info rsp: type 2 result 0
>         Extended feature mask 0x00b8
>           Enhanced Retransmission mode
>           Streaming mode
>           FCS Option
>           Fixed Channels
>   HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
>       handle 1 packets 1
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 10
>       L2CAP(s): Info req: type 3
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 20
>       L2CAP(s): Info rsp: type 3 result 0
>         Fixed channel list 0x00000002
>           L2CAP Signalling Channel
>   HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
>       handle 1 packets 1
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 16
>       L2CAP(s): Connect rsp: dcid 0x0040 scid 0x0040 result 0 status 0
>         Connection successful
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 27
>       L2CAP(s): Config req: dcid 0x0040 flags 0x00 clen 15
>         MTU 1013 
>         RFC 0x00 (Basic) 
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 27
>       L2CAP(s): Config req: dcid 0x0040 flags 0x00 clen 15
>         MTU 1013 
>         RFC 0x00 (Basic) 
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 18
>       L2CAP(s): Config rsp: scid 0x0040 flags 0x00 result 0 clen 4
>         MTU 1013 
>   HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
>       handle 1 packets 2
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 18
>       L2CAP(s): Config rsp: scid 0x0040 flags 0x00 result 0 clen 4
>         MTU 1013 
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 8
>       L2CAP(d): cid 0x0040 len 4 [psm 3]
>         RFCOMM(s): SABM: cr 1 dlci 0 pf 1 ilen 0 fcs 0x1c 
>   HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
>       handle 1 packets 1
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 8
>       L2CAP(d): cid 0x0040 len 4 [psm 3]
>         RFCOMM(s): UA: cr 1 dlci 0 pf 1 ilen 0 fcs 0xd7 
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 18
>       L2CAP(d): cid 0x0040 len 14 [psm 3]
>         RFCOMM(s): PN CMD: cr 1 dlci 0 pf 0 ilen 10 fcs 0x70 mcc_len 8
>         dlci 2 frame_type 0 credit_flow 15 pri 7 ack_timer 0
>         frame_size 1008 max_retrans 0 credits 7
>   HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
>       handle 1 packets 1
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 18
>       L2CAP(d): cid 0x0040 len 14 [psm 3]
>         RFCOMM(s): PN RSP: cr 0 dlci 0 pf 0 ilen 10 fcs 0xaa mcc_len 8
>         dlci 2 frame_type 0 credit_flow 14 pri 7 ack_timer 0
>         frame_size 1007 max_retrans 0 credits 7
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 8
>       L2CAP(d): cid 0x0040 len 4 [psm 3]
>         RFCOMM(s): SABM: cr 1 dlci 2 pf 1 ilen 0 fcs 0x59 
>   HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
>       handle 1 packets 1
>   HCI Event: PIN Code Request (0x16) plen 6
>       bdaddr D4:93:98:C6:9A:DA
>   ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 8
>       L2CAP(d): cid 0x0040 len 4 [psm 3]
>         RFCOMM(s): DISC: cr 0 dlci 0 pf 1 ilen 0 fcs 0x9c 
>   < ACL data: handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 8
>       L2CAP(d): cid 0x0040 len 4 [psm 3]

Comment: There are lots of different ways to do paring. Command line. Graphical UI. Python code. C code. etc. So without telling us what you are trying to achieve it is not clear how to answer. If you want to do it from the command line then use the `bluetoothctl` program. Within `bluetoothctl` run `agent on` then `discover on` to scan for the mobile device. Ensure the mobile device is discoverable. Once the scan finds the mobile device then run `pair <mobile device mac address>`.

Comment: I need to do it by C code using HCI commands. Is it possible? If possible can you please mention the command sequence and its repsonse format. If you can show me some example then it would be great.

Comment: This https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html got some useful examples to connect and pair using HCI commands.